File upload element is not listing in Drupal 10 Webform
i am creating a form in Drupal 10 using Webform. i am able add elements like "Textfield", "TextArea" etc. When i try to add "File upload", nothing is listing. Please find the attachment for the screenshot. Please help to fix this and add file upload field in the form.

For upload file, you can find the answer her: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/232586/webform-file-upload-field

i have checked the above solution. but still  it not showing any "File Upload Elements".

Do you have init the $settings['file_private_path'] in the right settings.php ? And clear drupal cache ?
You can also verify in "/admin/structure/webform/config/elements/" if the file element is available
